# 16.04 LTS Ubuntu boots slowly after dual boot to Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, fstab, user-space

I have had a dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu for a month or so. I have been able to go back and forth with no issues until recently. After booting Windows, I booted Ubuntu and it dropped to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox. I was able to boot by using the following command:

```
(initramfs) fsck /dev/sdaX
```

Now, I can boot, but it takes a long time. Also, I had to edit the fstab, so that my ntfs partition would automount like it used to.

See `systemd-analyze` results below:

```
Startup finished in 8.520s (kernel) + 3min 385ms (userspace) = 3min 8.905s
```

[systemd-analyze plot results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp7Kz.jpg)

Here is the most important part of the dmesg:

http://freetexthost.com/dyq2fe4az3

/etc/fstab text:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

#/dev/sda5
UUID=96eb174d-6c89-4730-a55f-e5f037a074b1   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
/dev/sda2   /media/windows  ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0   0
#/dev/sda6
UUID=3734f2a5-4ea4-445c-813e-7369c96b414f   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Four part fix... Windows hibernation file, fsck, disk NCQ errors, and bad blocks...

**Part #1:**

If the NTFS drives are mounting as read-only, its probably because Ubuntu thinks their filesystems are unclean, probably due to hibernation, or a damaged file system. Do this...

In Windows...

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

**Part #2:**

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Part #3:**

Edit /etc/default/grub

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

In `Terminal`...

```
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

**Part #4:**

**Your hard disk may be going bad**, and has some bad blocks that it's having trouble reading and reassigning.

## Backup your data now!

If Part #1 - #3 don't fix the problem, then continue with Part #4

## Don't do the following on a SSD drive!

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start a `terminal` window

  - `sudo e2fsck -cck /dev/sda5` # try to map out bad blocks
  - `reboot`

Comment: I tried this. I did step #1 then step #3 then step #2 because I did it before step #2 was edited in. A couple things:

Comment: @AustinTackaberry  Did you do part #4?

Comment: I did part #1 then step #3 then part #2 because I did it before part #2 was edited in.

A couple things: I couldn't find the fast startup checkbox, so I did it via the command line: `powercfg –h on`

Also, part #2 was pretty glitchy for me. I took some pictures and uploaded them to an [imgur album](https://imgur.com/a/OT7Wl)

I did not yet try part 4

Comment: @AustinTackaberry the fsck looks fine.

Comment: I have a SSD, so I won't do part 4!

Comment: @AustinTackaberry with an SSD, it's very important that you check the manufacturer's web site for firmware upgrades.

Comment: I ran the Kingston SSD Toolbox, and it said there are no new updates at this time

Comment: Then I'd say that your SSD is failing.